# Make SciTE open new files in the current process

Tags: text-editors, scite

I'm moving from my past editor of choice, Notepad++ to SciTE which is a bit faster and works better for me productivity-wise. The only current concern I have with SciTE is that new files open in a new process not the current one.

Is there a setting I can change or variable I have to set to make SciTE open new files in the current process? (Something similar to how Notepad++ does it?)

If it will help any, my current OS of choice is Windows on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
check.if.already.open
```

Set it to 1 in a SciTE config file (reachable from the menu "Options" -> "Open User Options File"), and simply add

```
check.if.already.open=1
```

in this file, and save.

This, and lots more on https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html